# Using Mod_Rewrite To Rebuild Directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm sure this is something simple, but no matter what I do it seems I break my file. With that said, what I am trying to do is use mod_rewrite to setup a bilingual website. I'm going to be using $_Get to define the language. I am then planning on using mod_rewrite to make at a little more SEO friendly. So instead of having every page like this: http://www.shiningashes.net/index.php?lg=en or http://www.shiningashes.net/support.php?lg=en I want the site to be like http://www.shiningashes.net/en/support. So how can I get is so that mod rewrite breaks down the url into chunks and rebuilds it? (http://www. *Root domain* / *language* / *file-directory name*)

Comment: You already know to use mod_rewrite, why not read the docs?

Comment: I have been, but I can't seem to figure out how to do what I am trying to so I was hoping that someone who has a lot more experience with this than I do can help. I have figure out how to do it for every single directory manually, but I am hoping for a while card solution. My problem is that i'm not seeing a way to get the file name, parse out the extension, and then adding it back into the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/(.+)$ $2.php?lg=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

#EXternal redirect /support.php?lg=en from to /en/support
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.php\?lg=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I was wondering, how do I get it so that the $2.php?lg=$1 version redirects to the ^([A-Z]{2})/(.+)$ version? I am just learning how to work with all of this. I have looked things up, but nothing I try works.. I tried using RewriteCond and testing against the host, and the reference point but can't seem to get it to redirect. I have googles how to do stuff like this, read documents.. I just learn best by seeing a working example of what I am trying to do and debugging what I did.

Comment: See edited answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only time you will have a two letter first level directory is when specifying the language, the following should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z]{2})/(.*) $2?lg=$1 [QSA, L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule  ^/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ /$2.php?lg=$1
```

This should rewrite `http://www.shiningashes.net/en/support` to `http://shiningashes.net/support.php?lg=en`

Excellent documentation here:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html